# Error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to figure out why `this.diskChoice.options.push` is undefined, it looks most likely a scoping issue.

```
----SNIP----
import {RestService, WebSocketService} from '../../../../services/';
----SNIP----

@Component({
   selector : 'bootenv-attach-form',
   template : `<entity-form [conf]="this"></entity-form>`
})

export class BootEnvAttachFormComponent {

      ----SNIP----

  protected route_success: string[] = [ 'bootenv', 'status' ];
      ----SNIP----


  public fieldConfig: FieldConfig[] =[
    {
      type: 'select', 
      name: 'dev', 
      placeholder: 'Member Disk',
    },
    {
      type: 'checkbox', 
      name: 'expand', 
      placeholder: 'Use all disk space',
    },

  ]
  protected diskChoice:  any = [];

  constructor(    ----SNIP----, protected ws: WebSocketService,----SNIP----){
}



  afterInit(entityForm: any) {
    this.entityForm = entityForm;
    this.diskChoice = _.find(this.fieldConfig, {'name':'dev'});
    this.ws.call('disk.get_unused').subscribe((res)=>{
      res.forEach((item) => {
        this.diskChoice.options.push({label : item[1], value : item[0]});
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at bootenv-attach-form.component.ts:61

Comment: Because `this.diskChoice.options` is undefined ?

Comment: if `this.diskChoice = []` then almost surely `this.diskChoice.options` is `undefined`. Do you mean to `this.diskChoice.push` instead? Why try to find options property of array?

Comment: Also, why declare `diskChoice: any = []` instead of `diskChoice: any[] = []`? If you let typescript infer the type as an array, it likely would have pointed out this bug at compile time.